# Попытка использовать параметры запроса приводит к ошибке 500

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Не работает ООП-стиль работы с MySQL (вернее, если можно так сказать, часть этого стиля). Обычные запросы без обработки работают нормально, аля

```
$mysqli -> query(...);
```

А ежели я стараюсь обрабатывать запрос перед его исполнением, используя prepare/bind_param/execute

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE `LOGIN`=?');
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $USERNAME);
$stmt -> execute();
```

То вылетает ошибка 500... Что делать?

Comment: Не используйте только верхний регистр для названия переменных - договорились использовать такой синтаксис для констант. Константа: `USERNAME`. Переменные: `$Username`, `$UserName`, `$username`, `$userName`, `$UsErNaMe`...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ваша конструкция ничего не делает. Так же, возможно у Вас ошибка в синтаксисе. Вот так наверное будет правильней.

```
 $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LOGIN=?', $USERNAME);
```

Далее Вы просто исполняете подготовленный при помощи prepare запрос. Он выполняется, но Вы не получаете при этом никаких данных. Посмотрите в класс $mysqli. Там должны быть методы для получения данных.

Comment: Это ничего не меняет. Я весь код не вставил, в дальнейшем я получаю результат и делаю с ним свои дела

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите работать с объектом $stmt, то для начала нужно его инициализировать:

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> stmt_init();
// а затем уже формировать подготовленный запрос:
$stmt -> prepare('SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE `LOGIN`=?');
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $USERNAME);
$stmt -> execute();
```

Далее доступны будут все методы, которые вы используете.

Еще одна оговорка: должны быть установлены все драйвера и модули для работы с mysqli. А именно: php5-mysqli, php5-mysqlnd, либо другие, которые могут их заменить. [ссылка на мануал по установке расширения mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.installation.php)

Comment: Ф-ция 'prepare' и без этого создаёт объект stmt, так что его инициализация тут лишняя.

Comment: Да, согласен, в мануалах именно так написано. Уже не помню, почему использую явную инициализацию, но, возможно, были причины. Может, бОльшая интуитивность кода?